# How can I add elements for mobile size only?

Tags: html, css

I'm working with a template and using Bootstrap 4. On a desktop the template has a phone number and email link at the top above the navbar.

On mobile, I want to have my logo centered, and underneath it, to have the telephone/email and social media links.

The CSS/Javascript causes them to disappear well before mobile size.

Desktop view:

[image: Desktop View]

Mobile view:

[image: Mobile View]

I'm stumped as to how to go about doing this. I can provide the CSS for whatever class is necessary, but I'm not sure what is relevant.

Here's the markup:

```
<div class="subnav">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

     <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="social-icons-subnav">


                        <a href="mailto:Lwallaceconstruction@gmail.com"><span class="ti-email"></span>Lwallaceconstruction@gmail.com</a>  
                        <a href="tel:1-530-680-8255"><span class="ti-mobile"></span>1-530-680-8255</a>

      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="right">
                        <div class="social-icons-subnav">
                            <a href="#"><span class="ti-facebook"></span></a>
                            <a href="#"><span class="ti-dribbble"></span></a>
                            <a href="#"><span class="ti-twitter"></span></a>
                            <a href="#"><span class="ti-linkedin"></span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
     </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- subnav end -->

  <!-- nav -->
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

       <!-- menu mobile display -->
       <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
       <span class="icon icon-bar"></span> 
       <span class="icon icon-bar"></span> 
       <span class="icon icon-bar"></span></button> 

      <!-- logo --> 
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img alt="logo" src="img/logo.png"></a>
```

Comment: Please Include enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have a ton of Css it is a huge list that came with the template. How am I supposed to link all of it? Part of my problem is that I do not know what classes to identify, i have looked through all of them and don't understand how to create a solution. So by looking at the markup, i thought others might be able to suggest where to look/edit. Is that not reasonable?

Comment: @nineborn, what works well on SO is cases with the minimum amount of code. Your example has maybe ~20 custom classes. What I'd recommend is try to put together a case with the bare minimum, and update this question. What I suspect, is you will actually find your problem as you're doing that.